# Powershell Get-ChildItem returns object not array

Tags: arrays

It seems `Get-ChildItem` returns a single object instead of an array of one object if it only finds one item. For example this returns 5:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "e*.txt"
$files.length
```

But the following should return 1 but returns 61321:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "exact.txt"
$files.length
```

The 61321 is the size in bytes of the file exact.txt.

How can we consistently check if there were files found?

Answer (score 15):

It is a "feature" of `Get-ChildItem` that it won't return an array with one item but instead the single object. To force an array append `@` as in:

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter "e*.txt")
```

Alternatively if you just want to check if there are NO files you can do:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "exact.txt"
if (!$files) {"No Files"}
```

Comment: Note, if `Get-ChildItem` returns `$null` you will still end up with an array with 1 item in it: `$files[0] -eq $null` will be `true`! You will not get an empty array with length 0. See issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523767/powershell-function-return-array